# Exit probability on a Brownian motion from an interval

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Suppose that $B_s, s \geq 0$ is a one dimensional Brownian motion starts at $0$.

Define the event $A$:$B_s$ exits the interval $(-a,a)$ before time $t$.

Prove that

$P(A)\leq \frac{2\sqrt{2t}}{a\sqrt{\pi}}*\exp(\frac{-a^2}{2t})$

Is there any hint how to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T_a=\inf\{t:B_t=a\}$. Then by symmetry and the Reflection principle we get
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(A)&\le \mathsf{P}(T_a< t)+\mathsf{P}(T_{-a}< t)\\
&=4\mathsf{P}(B_t\ge a)=4\mathsf{P}(B_1\ge t^{-1/2}a)\le \frac{2\sqrt{2t}}{a\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{a^2}{2t}}.
\end{align}

Comment: i didn't understand why $P(T_a<t)< 2*P(B_t ≥ a)$?

Comment: @user115608 Reflection principle for the BM, i.e.
$$
\mathsf{P}(T_a<t)=2\mathsf{P}(B_t\ge a).
$$