# Probability that Brownian motion stays within a certain interval

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X_t$ be a non-standard Brownian motion with $X_t \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2 t)$ where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the Wiener process.

I am wondering whether there are any estimates on the process

$$M_T:=\sup_{t \in [0,T]} \vert X_t \vert$$

known? In other words, can we estimate

$$\mathcal P(M_T \ge a)$$ for any $a >0$?

Comment: This is very standard. You can obtain this probability using Reflection Principle.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy well.. "very standard" if you did not have the absolute value in the definition of M... with the absolute value it is less "standard" and less "easy"

Comment: Well, it is easier without the absolute value but even with absolute value I think it is standard.

Comment: Here is your answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336266/exit-probability-on-a-brownian-motion-from-an-interval

Comment: I think you can actually find an equality as opposed to an inequality in the answer I linked to. But looking for exit time results is the way to go.